# Is there a .NET IVI library for the Tektronix TBS1052B?

Tags: oscilloscope, library

I have a Tektronix TBS 1052B meter that I would like to control over a USB port, in a Windows/.NET environment. I am looking to use the IVI foundation's interface libraries in order to do this. I am searching through the driver's section on NI's website. Here are the drivers that they have listed for my device:

[image: Driver Download Options]

Will I be able to control the scope, using either of these drivers? I do understand that I may not be able to, because LV and LW are explicitly mentioned. But what I am thinking, is that by installing either one of these drivers, the *raw* DLL/IVI-driver may *also* be installed. I am thinking that I would therefore be able to access the IVI library directly. Is that the case?

Comment: Why would you not use the Tektronix framework?  That would install the necessary driver.

Comment: @bdegnan If I knew there was one then I would be using it. I searched the NI site high and low, trying to stay in line with the "IVI" standards and what not. Can I get a link?

Comment: My other problem is that the programmer's reference manual doesn't really cover the basics of installing the framework or how to begin, instead they just jump right into the SCPI command set, which is totally not helpful for someone who has no idea what they're doing.

Comment: The driver is http://www.tek.com/search/apachesolr_search/tekvisa?filters=type%3Asoftware somewhere. You need the TEKVISA driver for your scope.  You then need to send the SCPI commands for the scope. Those commands are usually outlined in the manual.

Comment: @bdegnan because of how horrible these websites are to navigate and find stuff (I ended up using NationalInstruments.VisaNS which contained the 1052B) I am actually thinking to just maintain a repo with copies of the DLLs to avoid the whole mess of having to deal with Tek installers and framework and just avoid as much of dealing with Tek as possible.